# Send push notifications to a specific logged user with pinpoint

Tags: react-native, aws-lambda, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

Im developing a react native app integrated with aws-amplify and aws mobile hub.

We currently logged our user into cognito.

im trying to send a push notification to a specific endpoint Id, but i cannot see how to set that endpointId, in the node js (im using lambda) documentation for pinpoint only exist getEnpoint, but requires EnpointId and i cannot find where is it.

```
 app.post('/asdf/get/endpoint', function (req, res) {
  pinpoint.getEndpoint({
    ApplicationId: APP_ID_PINPOINT,
    EndpointId: req.body.userId
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({ error: err });
    } else {
      res.json({ data: data });
    }
  });
});
```

How can  set the enpointId (userId) to an already logged user and then, every time i need to send a push to him i just get that enpoint and send a push to all the devices attached to it?

Or, i have to store all the tokens from the user (DynamoDb), and send messages to all the devices separately? (with pinpoint sendMessage)